# How can I centre a circular progress bar in a UIView using Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, storyboard

I'm having quite a bit of difficulty simply ensuring a circular progress bar is always in the centre of the `UIView` it is associated to.

This is what is happening:

[image]

Ignore the grey region, this is simply the `UIView` on a placeholder card. The red is the `UIView` I have added as an outlet to the `UIViewController`.

Below is the code for the class that I have made:

```
class CircleProgress: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    var progressLyr = CAShapeLayer()
    var trackLyr = CAShapeLayer()

    var progressClr = UIColor.red {
       didSet {
          progressLyr.strokeColor = progressClr.cgColor
       }
    }

    var trackClr = UIColor.black {
       didSet {
          trackLyr.strokeColor = trackClr.cgColor
       }
    }

    private func setupView() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let centre = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height/2)

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centre,
                                      radius: 10,
                                      startAngle: 0,
                                      endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi,
                                      clockwise: true)

        trackLyr.path = circlePath.cgPath
        trackLyr.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLyr.strokeColor = trackClr.cgColor
        trackLyr.lineWidth = 5.0
        trackLyr.strokeEnd = 1.0

        layer.addSublayer(trackLyr)
    }
}
```

The aim is simply to have all 4 edges of the black circle touching the edges of the red square.

Any help is hugely appreciated. I'm thinking it must be too obvious but this has cost me too many hours tonight. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no frame being passed when creating the object. No need for changing anything to your code. For sure you have to change the width and the height to whatever you want.

Here is an example...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white

        // Add circleProgress
        addCircleProgress()
    }

    private func addCircleProgress() {
        let circleProgress = CircleProgress(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 50, y: self.view.center.x - 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        self.view.addSubview(circleProgress)
    }
}

class CircleProgress: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    var progressLyr = CAShapeLayer()
    var trackLyr = CAShapeLayer()

    var progressClr = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            progressLyr.strokeColor = progressClr.cgColor
        }
    }

    var trackClr = UIColor.black {
        didSet {
            trackLyr.strokeColor = trackClr.cgColor
        }
    }

    private func setupView() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let centre = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height/2)

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centre,
                                      radius: 50,
                                      startAngle: 0,
                                      endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi,
                                      clockwise: true)

        trackLyr.path = circlePath.cgPath
        trackLyr.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLyr.strokeColor = trackClr.cgColor
        trackLyr.lineWidth = 5.0
        trackLyr.strokeEnd = 1.0

        layer.addSublayer(trackLyr)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what if we change the frame of circular view ? we need to make changes in circular view ?

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

1. I’d suggest making this `CircularProgress` take up the whole view. If you want this to be inset within the view, then, fine, add a property for that. In my example below, I created a property called `inset` to capture this value.
2. Make sure to update your path in `layoutSubviews`. Especially if you use constraints, you want this to respond to size changes. So add these layers from `init`, but update the path in `layoutSubviews`.
3. Don’t reference `frame` (which is the location within the superview coordinate system). Use `bounds`. And inset it by half the line width, so the circle doesn’t exceed the bounds of the view.
4. You created a progress color and progress layer, but didn’t use either one. I’ve guessed you wanted that to show the progress within the track.
5. You are stroking your path from 0 to 2π. People tend to expect these circular progress views to start from -π/2 (12 o’clock) and progress to 3π/2. So I’ve updated the path to use those values. But use whatever you want.
6. If you want, you can make it `@IBDesignable` if you want to see this rendered in IB.

Thus, pulling that together, you get:

```
@IBDesignable
public class CircleProgress: UIView {

    @IBInspectable
    public var lineWidth: CGFloat = 5              { didSet { updatePath() } }

    @IBInspectable
    public var strokeEnd: CGFloat = 1              { didSet { progressLayer.strokeEnd = strokeEnd } }

    @IBInspectable
    public var trackColor: UIColor = .black        { didSet { trackLayer.strokeColor = trackColor.cgColor } }

    @IBInspectable
    public var progressColor: UIColor = .red       { didSet { progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor } }

    @IBInspectable
    public var inset: CGFloat = 0                  { didSet { updatePath() } }

    private lazy var trackLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.strokeColor = trackColor.cgColor
        layer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        return layer
    }()

    private lazy var progressLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
        layer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        return layer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePath()
    }
}

private extension CircleProgress {
    func setupView() {
        layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }

    func updatePath() {
        let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth / 2 + inset, dy: lineWidth / 2 + inset)

        let centre = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        let radius = min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centre,
                                radius: radius,
                                startAngle: -.pi / 2,
                                endAngle: 3 * .pi / 2,
                                clockwise: true)

        trackLayer.path = path.cgPath
        trackLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth

        progressLayer.path = path.cgPath
        progressLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

Comment: i am confused in let vs lazy var when creating UI elements ... can you guide me which one is better ? as i have seen you are using lazy var to create UI elements

Comment: We use `let` wherever we can. But I happen to be instantiating it with a closure. But a closure can’t reference other properties during the initialization process. So I’ve made it a lazy property, and now the initialization closure can reference other properties. If you find that confusing, use `let`, but don’t configure inside the closures, but rather move the configuration code to `setupView`. It’s a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Update this function

```
private func setupView() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let centre = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centre,
                                      radius: bounds.maxX/2,
                                      startAngle: 0,
                                      endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi,
                                      clockwise: true)

        trackLyr.path = circlePath.cgPath
        trackLyr.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLyr.strokeColor = trackClr.cgColor
        trackLyr.lineWidth = 5.0
        trackLyr.strokeEnd = 1.0

        layer.addSublayer(trackLyr)
    }
```